# How can I get category id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a function that can retrieve the `category_id` of the current location. I want to have the category url taken as well as the id of the category of the subject I have taken.
How can I do it?

posts table for keep my post: https://prnt.sc/PEqSq2mM5NKM
categories table for keep my categories: https://prnt.sc/WK7n8kAGoUWD

My code:

```php
function Get_url($url){
    $veri=[];

    $datas = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE url = ?');
    $datas->execute([$url]);
    $data = $datas->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($data as $key=>$value){
        $datas = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = ?, category_url = ?');
        $datas->execute([$value['id']], [$value['category_url']]);
        $veri[] = $datas->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function get_url($url){
    
    global $db;
    $veri = array('status' => 'success');

    $sql = "SELECT
            t2.category_id,
            t2.category_url
                FROM posts t1
                INNER JOIN categories t2 ON t1.category_id = t2.id
                WHERE t1.url = ?
                LIMIT 1";

    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    if( $query->rowCount == 0 ):
       $veri = array('status' => 'error');
    else:
        $row = $query->execute([$url]);
        $veri = array('category_id', $row['category_id'], 'category_url', $row['category_url']);
    endif;

    return $veri;

}
```

to be able to use the function:

```
$get_cat      = get_url($url);

if( $get_cat['status'] == 'success' ):
    $category_id  = $get_cat['category_id'];
    $category_url = $get_cat['category_url'];
else:
    echo 'could not find category';
endif;
```

Comment: Instead of a 'try this', please try to explain why and/or how you got to this answer :)

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right @Martijn :) Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But it didn't work! I could not understand what you are trying to do in the code, how to pull the yield and whether there is a place to change in the code. I would be glad if you could explain. I didn't change anything while applying the code you gave. $data['id'] I tried to print as

Comment: hello @RBT I'm trying to pull the category of yield. I want to have the id of the category that I pulled, as well as the category url next to it. how can I do it?
My code and tables are available at the beginning of the thread.

Comment: Hello @ilker the function above already gives you category id and category URL through post URL. I also have added how you can use the function.